# JNA UnsatisfiedLinkError exception

Tags: java, java-native-interface, jna

I am trying to  deploy my application that invokes native calls using JNA library, but I get the following exception.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'myCustomDLL': Native library (win32-x86-64/myCustomDLL.dll) not found in resource path ([myproject/target/classes/, ...some jars...])

What do I need to do in order to invoke the function correctly?

Any help much appreciated

Comment: JNA will attempt to load from `jna.library.path` and if not there will look in your resource path according to [this strategy](http://twall.github.io/jna/4.1.0/com/sun/jna/NativeLibrary.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found the answer to this. Basically, I needed to install Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable package to install all the necessary DLLs needed for JNA to work. Thanks for other responses to this question.

Answer (score 0):

You must put your dll library (with native code) on application java.library.path.

See :
http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/java-library-path-what-is-it-and-how-to-use/

Edit:

Post your project layout here. And how you run your app.

Comment: I added my dll in /webapps/classes folder, but still does not pick it up. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Here is the layout of my application:
1) The DLL location: /webapps/classes\myCustomDLL.dll

2) Inside my Java Folder, I do the following:
CLibrary INSTANCE3 = (CLibrary)
    Native.loadLibrary((Platform.isWindows() ? "myCustomDLL" : "c"),
      CLibrary.class);

Comment: Have you check your java.library.path (check link which I posted)?

Comment: What is the <main class>> Is that the main class for my application where the actual dll is loaded?

Comment: In this context is a class containing public static void main() method (java class), not native class.

Comment: I am deploying my app as a war file in Tomcat and sending a request via SoapUI. As soon as loadLibrary call happens, it fails with that error

Comment: Also, that my custom DLL is dependent on other DLLs

Comment: All dll must be on java.library.path of Tomcat java. Could you check how java.library.path looks like on this server, copy all neccesary dll's to this location and check again ?

Comment: Also you could use http://one-jar.sourceforge.net to deploy whole app as one jar with native libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the DLL is executable.
Check the dependant DLLs are all executable.

With windows explorer, right click on DLL -> property -> security and verify execution rights.